# Alfresco CMIS query : strict equality operator = seems to behave as LIKE operator

Tags: alfresco, cmis

Attached a screenshot of workbench query that does not work because all objects containing the word 'TEST' are returned.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDIbD.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defined m.apms.type in your model, did you turn off tokenization or did you take the default? If you took the default, the string is tokenized and you will not be able to do an exact match with that query.

Comment: You could get around this (if changing the model/reindexing is not an option, and you need to have strict equality) by using Alfresco FTS rather than CMIS.

Comment: Thanks Jeff it was the solution (<tokenized> false </ tokenised)
after reindexation

Comment: Glad that worked @ami. If you get a chance, please accept the answer as correct.